# Gwt 2.2 new HTML5 audio docs?

Tags: gwt

I am searching for the documentation for the new html5 audio added in GWT 2.2  but all I can find is this http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/media/client/Audio.html

That does not really list the available methods though.Is there any better documentation available?

There does not seem to be any methods such as .play() etc???

Comment: Wow I feel goofy.It is in the AudioElement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that Audio object, you will need to call the `getAudioElement()` function, which implement `MediaElement` and has all the functions you're looking for like `play()`, `pause()`, `setVolume()`, `getCurrentSrc()`, etc.

The official documentation is [here](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/dom/client/AudioElement.html).